# How to block all the notifications in the android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I can able to block the incoming and outgoing calls in android.
I even able to block the SMS's only if I made my app as default SMS app by taking the user permission at runtime.

I believe, there is a way to block the notifications or close the notifications instantly when the device receives the notification.

Comment: Wondered! How you can able to block the incoming and outgoing calls programmatically?

Comment: @RAAAAM enable airplane mode hahahhaha

Comment: @eminem Changing state of airplane mode is not possible for third-party apps. Android removed that feature to change the airplane mode feature.

Comment: @RAAAAM 

Incoming Calls:
`telephonyService.endCall();` // this will help to reject the calls

Comment: @RAAAM 
Out going calls:
Manifest file: 
        `<receiver
            android:name=".BlockOutgoing"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

 `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        setResultData(null);
    }`